# How to go back one step onclick event in a mobile menu

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a mobile menu version of a site. I already applied most of the actions when navigating the menu, but I'm having problems with the "Go Back" ('atras') button. I need this button to trigger a step back when clicking on it, but at this moment it is applying the action to all the submenus.

Example:

```
MenuItem 01 >> MenuItem 02 >> MenuItem 03
```

When navigating this menu you will go inside a submenu in order 01 > 02 > 03 and to go back the logical way would be 03 > 02 > 01. However at the moment it is triggering from 03 to 01 step, so it is ignoring the step 02.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Menu implementation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header container__flex--between">
        <div>
            <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/95x28' id="hideMe" class='logoABCdin' alt='ABCdin'/>
            <div id='showMe' class='hideMe' onclick="goBackAction()">atras</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container__close">
            <span><b>Cerrar</b></span>
            <span><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="container__mask">
        <div class="main__container__box">
            <div class="sub__container__box--zero">
                <ul class="container__box">
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between" onclick="dragger('electro'); backDraggerHide('hideMe'); backDraggerShow('showMe')">
                        <span class="item">
                            Electro
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Línea blanca
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Telefonía
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Computación
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Dormitorio
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Muebles
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Decohogar
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Outdoor y deporte
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Entretenimiento
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Infantil
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sub__container__box--hidden" id="electro">  
                <ul class="container__box">
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between" onclick="dragger('tvs')">
                        <span class="item toAll">
                            Todo electro
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            TV & Video
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Audio
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Audifonos
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Dormitorio
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="item">
                            Smart home
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sub__container__box--hidden" id="tvs">
                <ul class="container__box">
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="subItem">
                            Televisores LED
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="subItem">
                            Reproductores DVD-Blue Ray-TV portatíl
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="container__menu container__flex--between">
                        <span class="subItem">
                            Accesorios de TV
                        </span>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="./js/dragger.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
function dragger(prop) {

    var element = document.getElementById(prop);
    element.setAttribute("class", "sub__container__box--hiddenShowMe");

}

function draggerOf(prop) {

    var element = document.getElementById(prop);
    element.setAttribute("class", "sub__container__box--hiddenHideMe");

}


function backDraggerHide(prop) {

    var backDraggerLocator = document.getElementById(prop);
    backDraggerLocator.setAttribute("class", "hideMe")

}

function backDraggerShow(prop) {

    var backDraggerLocator = document.getElementById(prop);
    backDraggerLocator.setAttribute("class", "showMe goBack")

}

function goBackAction() {

    let electro = document.getElementById('electro').querySelectorAll('ul > li')[0].innerText;

    let tvs = document.getElementById('tvs').querySelectorAll('ul > li')[0].innerText;

    if (electro === 'TODO ELECTRO') {

        document.getElementById('electro').setAttribute("class", "sub__container__box--hiddenHideMe");

    }

    if (tvs === 'Televisores LED') {

        document.getElementById('tvs').setAttribute("class", "sub__container__box--hiddenHideMe");

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the element with id `tvs`? I see that being referenced in the onclick but never defined.

Comment: Sorry, I'd updated the post with the full HTML...

Comment: I think I'm missing something. You mention the steps 03, 02, and 01. Can you call out what those exact steps you want in your code? Apologies for not understanding quickly.